# Where are the Designated Router in this picture?

Tags: ospf

I have the following network diagram and I want to know which interface on every router is the Designated Router?

I got the message that Router1 on interface 192.168.4.1 is the Designated Router but I do not know why?
Router1 does not have any Router-Id and Loopback-IP, so how can it be that this interface becomes Designated Router?
Compared to Router 2, which has a Router-Id and a Loopback - IP, its interface with the IP address 192.168.4.2 must become in my understanding the Designated Router.

[image]

I know the election has the following priority:

1) Highest priority
2) Router-Id
3) Loopback - IP
4) Interface - IP

Maybe, someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I will answer my question :)

Designated Router will be chosen the following way:

1) The highest Priority counts
2) The highest Router-Id
3) The highest Loopback - IP
4) The highest Interface - IP

Priority defaults to 1.

So, Router - Id counts in the beginning.
If Router - Id is missing and all the others, too, the highest Interface - Ip will be taken as the highest Router - Id.

In my example, let us take the Router 1:

It has neither a Router - ID nor a Loopback - Ip.
So, its highest Interface will be taken as the Router - Id and this one will be compared with Router 0s Router-Id.
Router1: 192.168.1.7 > Router0: 3.3.3.3